# Enable Backlog and Sprint Planning tool on TFS express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

If its possible to use the Backlog and Sprint Planning tool on TFS express 2013?

how can i enable it, because i can't see it even with Administrator Account? from visual studio 2012 ultimate team explorer i open the Web Access but open another page without any info to set the access level to full.

when i use http://[tfsServer]/tfs/DefaultCollection/Foundation%20Service/_backlogs/ return an error: "TF400409: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Backlog and sprint planning tools"

any idea, thanks in advance

Comment: Head to the webacess portal. Select a team project and configure the area and iteration paths from the "Home" tab. Then click on "Work". The backlog and other planning tools would be available here.

Comment: when i use [tfsServer]/tfs/DefaultCollection/Foundation%20Service/_backlogs/ return an error: "TF400409: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Backlog and sprint planning tools"

Comment: No, you can't do this on TFS Express. I would suggest checking out visualstudio.com and starting a VSOnline account, or upgrading to a full version of TFS.